# Jenkins Credentials with seed job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I've got a small Kubernetes cluster from our private cloud team but they want that we automate everything. I was told to use a Jenkins seed job to create all pipelines I need.
I figured out how to do this but there is a small issue.
I need to store the credentials of the docker registry manually within jenkins. Is there any way I can automate the credential creation? Or is there any other way to authenticate against the private registry beside of using

```
container('docker') {
                    withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'dockerRegistry', url: "https://registrurl/"]) {
```

I've found examples using groovy code like this to create jenkins credentials:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*

// parameters
def jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPasswordParameters = [
        description:  'Description here',
        id:           'key-id-here',
        secret:       '12345678901234567890',
        userName:     'your-username-here'
]

// get Jenkins instance
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

// get credentials domain
def domain = Domain.global()

// get credentials store
def store = jenkins.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()

// define secret
def jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(
        CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
        jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPasswordParameters.id,
        jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPasswordParameters.description,
        jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPasswordParameters.userName,
        jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPasswordParameters.secret
)

// add credential to store
store.addCredentials(domain, jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPassword)

// save to disk
jenkins.save()
```

It is working perfectly within the Jenkins Script Console but it is not working from any Job I've created.

I always get errors like this:

```
jenkins_credentials.groovy: 28: unable to resolve class UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl 
 @ line 28, column 38.
   def jenkinsKeyUsernameWithPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(
```

Comment: How are you invoking this Groovy code that you found within the pipeline?

Comment: My first attempt was to invoke it as groovy File from Job DSL and also tried it through Pipeline with this jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('setup credentials') {
            steps {
                load 'kubernetes/jenkins/jenkins_credentials.groovy'
            }
         }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can automate credentials creation with jenkins configuration as code plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/